# Interpolating using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, interpolation, large-datasets

I have 2 datasets. They have exactly the same columns and the data for the second dataset was collected the day after first dataset.

When I perform Diffusion interpolation with barriers on the **first dataset** - it works perfectly. See image:
[image]

But when I do the same interpolation for the **second dataset** - it's really bad. Like that:
[image]

When I extract a part of **second dataset** - it's still bad:
[image]

But when I group a **part of first dataset with a part of second** one - it's again fine:
[image]

I've checked everything I can, I can't understand what is the problem with the second dataset.

The small part of the second dataset, full temperature data for 2nd dataset and land file for barriers could be downloaded here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1-qjTov7WPBhAQ1JMS9KjdKTxjiyPm6Tn?usp=sharing

Comment: Check your output cell size?

Comment: @ycartwhelen 
It's automatically suggested value 0,09063912. Previously I had no problems for other datasets with automatically calculated cell sizes

Comment: But are the cell sizes for the two datasets the same? Dataset 2 looks like it has much coarser cells.

Comment: @ycartwhelen Yes, they are different. Like for the first smaller dataset which is working perfectly the cell sizes are 6,321199 and for the second dataset which interpolates awfully the cell sizes are 0,09063912

Comment: @ycartwhelen It finally worked, when I changed cell size to 2,11436. Thanks for bringing my attention to the cell sizes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It finally worked, when I changed cell size to 2,11436 from 0,09063912.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just ran your sample in the tool using TempCels and I got this:

[image: sample]

So it seems to work for me. It might be a display issue rather than a processing issue, i.e. the pyramids failed to correctly be built. I would try re-running the build pyramids and statistics on your output raster. For the record I wrote the ouput to a file geodatabase.

Comment: Thanks for trying, and for me it started to work for this small data just after I restarted ArcGIS, but it still doesn't work for the whole dataset. I tried to rebuild pyramids and it said "WARNING 001274: The dimension of the dataset is smaller than 1024 x 1024, pyramids will not be built." 
I'm not eligible to share the whole dataset, but here is the data for temperature for the whole second dataset: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1MAdlZkE9FKbsre0LrRIkjTHmkED4Oisw?usp=sharing